# Grammaticality of the invented sentences

Tags: grammaticality

Which one would be better for Question A?

B1 or B2? Are both grammatical?

> 1. A: Do you love it that he will resign?  
>      B1: Yes, I love it.
>      B2: Yes, I love the situation.

Which one would be better for Question C?

D1 or D2? Are both grammatical?

> 2. C: Did Rumor have it that he will resign? 
>     
>      D1: Yes, Rumor had it.
>      D2: Yes, Rumor had the situation.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. It just wastes people's time.

Comment: @DavidRicherby This is categorically not the same question as the linked to one!!!!

Comment: @Araucaria There's no need to shout. Everything in this question is already included in the linked one, except for the questions to which the statements are intended to be answers. This question is just a slightly reorganized version of the other one, with some of the options deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using 'the situation' is incorrect, but it is unnecessarily long and not at all idiomatic. English typically uses the short answers with 'it', so if you want idiomatic English you should go with those.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I also think that B2 is acceptable answer for the A.    But, Do you mean that D2 is acceptable for the Question C ? Since for me it sounds bad.

Comment: To me both B2 and D2 sound unnatural. I wouldn't use 'the situation' unless I was referring to something that cannot be explained in just one sentence.

Comment: So you mean, B2 would sounds better if changed into ``Yes, I love the situation that he will resign.'' ?

Comment: No in that case I would still use it. I wouldn't use situation unless you had a whole explanation before that of multiple sentences. 'He will resign' is still a short and simple sentence that can easily be referred to by 'it'. Here you could use situation: 'What do you think about Mike considering to resign and the boss being really angry about it?' Here 'situation' works a lot better than 'it'.

Comment: I see. Really appreciate for your kind answer.!! I have one more question. Are either ones grammatical sentence?  ''Rumor had he will resign.'' and "I love he will resign.''

Comment: 'Rumor has it' is a fixed expression and does not work without the 'it'. I love also does not work without a noun that introduces the subclause. It doesn't necessarily need to be it, but a noun is needed, so 'I love he will resign' is incorrect. A few correct examples are: 'I love it that...', 'I love the fact that...', 'I love the way that...' etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yo wouldn't really say *do you love it that he resigned?*, because do you love is correct to use on a noun. *Resigned* is a verb. It would be correct to say:

> Are you happy that he resigned?

which the answer to could be both:

> Yes, I am happy
>   Yes, I am happy that he resigned

You could however say:

> I love the fact that he resigned

Which would make it a noun. Because *I love the fact* so love would be on fact, and that he resigned just the addition to the noun

The second sentence is more or less correct. And you would say:

> Yes rumour had it

Comment: What do you mean by "abstract"? "I love democracy" is a perfectly reasonable but "democracy" seems like a pretty abstract concept to me.

Comment: "Fact" is fairly abstract, since facts are mental constructs that mirror otherwise-inexpressible realities. Sometimes the fact doesn't actually reflect anything particularly physical either.

Comment: Oops. Incorrect. I just noticed it. It is on verbs not abstract. Fact is indeed fairly abstract. I love that he resigned is love to the verb. I love the fact is to a noun.